# Scrapy: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrapoxy'

Tags: linux, python-3.x, scrapy, twisted, scrapoxy

I have associated my scarpy scraper with Scrapoxy as in the [tutorial](https://scrapoxy.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorials/python-scrapy/index.html)

However, when i run the scraper on my server machine, I recieved the error with the below trace:

```
`2018-11-16 11:03:44 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.1 started (bot: 

myscraper)
2018-11-16 11:03:44 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.2.5.0, libxml2 2.9.8, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.5.1, w3lib 1.19.0, T
wisted 18.9.0, Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Apr 29 2018, 16:14:56) - [GCC 7.2.0], pyOpenSSL 18.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.0.2p  14 
Aug 2018), cryptography 2.3.1, Platform Linux-3.16.0-7-amd64-x86_64-with-debian-8.11
2018-11-16 11:03:44 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'myscraper', 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 1,
 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 3, 'LOG_FILE': 'trace', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'myscraper.spiders', 'RETRY_TIMES': 0, 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 
'SPIDER_MODULES': ['myscraper.spiders']}
2018-11-16 11:03:44 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2018-11-16 11:03:44 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:
2018-11-16 11:03:44 [twisted] CRITICAL: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1418, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "/usr/bin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 80, in crawl
    self.engine = self._create_engine()
  File "/usr/bin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 105, in _create_engine
    return ExecutionEngine(self, lambda _: self.stop())
  File "/usr/bin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 69, in __init__
    self.downloader = downloader_cls(crawler)
  File "/usr/bin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/__init__.py", line 88, in __init__
    self.middleware = DownloaderMiddlewareManager.from_crawler(crawler)
  File "/usr/bin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 58, in from_crawler
    return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
  File "/usr/bin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 34, in from_settings
    mwcls = load_object(clspath)
  File "/usr/bin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 44, in load_object
    mod = import_module(module)
  File "/usr/bin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrapoxy'`
```

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: can you please provide your code and have you checked what @Guillaume have written.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed `scrapyproxy`?

`pip install scrapyproxy`